# Diagramming "because of"

Tags: diagramming

I'm reading an article by DWT (https://www.dailywritingtips.com/because-of-and-due-to/), and I'm unable to diagram *I missed the class because of the rain.* Do I treat *because of* as the head of adverbial prepositional phrase modifying *missed* and attach *the rain* to it as the OoP?

Comment: Never mind "head". Treat _because of_ as a preposition; in fact, it's the preposition corresponding to the conjunction _because_. So if you convert a clause to a noun, you change the _because_ to _because of_. E.g, _I left because he insulted me/I left because of his insult to me._

Comment: Of course, ‘because’ comes from ‘by cause’.  ‘Of’ then comes naturally after ‘cause’ just as it comes naturally from ‘by way of’.

Answer (score 1):

***Because of*** is a preposition, and as any preposition it forms a prepositional phrase  (here: an adverbial modifier).

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

> ***because of***
>
> preposition
>
> : On account of;  by reason of.
>
> ‘they moved here because of the baby’
>
> Synonyms:
>
> on account of, as a result of, as a consequence of, owing to, by
>   reason of, on grounds of, by dint of, due to